# "dh_install" isn't overwriting a file

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I have defined an `install` file for my Debian packages, that puts a file (let's call it `foo`) in a directory. Existing instances that are using my package currently are using an older version of `foo`. When I try to install my new package, though, `dh_install` seems to create a `foo.dpkg-dist` file instead of replacing the file, which messes up the application.

I've seen that `conffiles` uses various flags such as `--force-confnew` to fix this, but I do not know if these affect `install` based files (I have tried all the options as well, to no avail). Is there a way I can force the `install` files to all be overwritten, instead of being installed with a suffix?